# Strange behaviour with autolayout and frame changing with iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9

I'm trying to create a view controller to simulate a classic weighing scale. I have a UIView subclass (DragView) to represent the weights, and a another UIView subclass (ContainerView) to simulate the plates os the scale.

When a DragView is drag over the ContainerView, I trigger an animation to place the DragView inside the ContainerView (changing the size if is necessary). But, if the user releases the DragView outside the ContainerView, then the DragView is animated to its original position and size.

Here you can see the DragView (in green) and two ContainerView (in clear Color above the "plates")

[image]

The original frame of the DragView is set with constraints (proportional width, top and leading). Everything looks fine but when I animate the DragView back to his original position, then I've got this.

[image]

See the difference in the DragView's frame?. Why is this happening?

Here are the relevant parts of my code.

DragView.m

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
  self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

  if (self) {
    _originalFrame = self.frame;
  }

  return self;
}

- (void)animateBackToOrigin
{
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
      self.frame = _originalFrame;
  }];
}
```

I've checked the `_originalFrame` values in both methods and it returned the same values.

**ANSWER:**

My mistake was setting the _originalFrame within `initWithCoder`, `layoutSubViews` is the right place. Because `layoutSubViews` is called every time the view is set, I added a check (with `CGRectIsEmpty`) in order to set the frame only if there is no value.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
  if (CGRectIsEmpty(_originalFrame)) {
    _originalFrame = self.frame;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is to early in initWithCoder: to take resulting frame. The view is just instantiated and not processed through layout process. I think, the best place is layoutSubviews method.

Comment: You put me on the right way and found a solution. I updated the question with the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When autolayout is present bad things will happen if you mess with frame.
Try instead of changing the full frame, change the .origin of the object

Comment: I thought about that, but the size will change too in many cases.